# How can I combine these regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

Four very identical regular expressions. I am replacing the strings with the following scalar values. How can this be more efficient?

```
$line =~ s/\[(receiver)\]/$receiver/g;
$line =~ s/\[(place)\]/$place/g;
$line =~ s/\[(position)\]/$position/g;
$line =~ s/\[(company)\]/$company/g;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, regexes aren't that smart, so they can't make decisions pertaining to the appropriate replacement for each case.

Comment: If you were using Python's re library - and I suspect Perl has similar functionality - you can call a function to generate the replacement for each match.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider just using a real templating system.  [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template%3a%3aToolkit) for instance is very easy.

Leaving that aside, you say you want it more efficient.  Is its current perceived inefficiency a problem?  If not, leave it alone.

You could do it all in one pass:

```
my %subst = (
    'receiver' => $receiver,
    'place'    => $place, 
    'position' => $position,
    'company'  => $company,
);
$line =~ s/\[(receiver|place|position|company)\]/$subst{$1}/g;
```

but this will act differently if, for instance, `$receiver` is 'place'.

Comment: +1 for showing the possible change in semantics when combining the expressions.

Comment: One the plus side, the new semantics are probably the desired semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's see, what you want:

if you want to 'evaluate' the value of variable, that name you found in the string, then, you need:

```
my $receiver = 'rcv';
my $place = 'plc';
my $position = 'pstn';
my $company = 'cmpn';
my $allVariableNames = join('|',qw(receiver place position company));
$line = '[receiver]';
$line =~ s/\[($allVariableNames)\]/'$'.$1/eg;
#$line =~ s/\[($allVariableNames)\]/eval('$'.$1)/eg; <- smarter and shorter variant
print $line,"\n"; #contain $receiver
print eval($line), "\n";   # evaluate ($receiver) => get rcv
```

it is another way to do this task, see **ysth**' answer above

Comment: instead of `s/\[($allVariableNames)\]/eval('$'.$1)/eg;` you can use `s/\[($allVariableNames)\]/'$'.$1/eeg;`

Answer (score 1):

For combining regular expressions, you really want to check out [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aAssemble).

**Update**: maybe a more complete example is in order:

```
my %subst = (
    'receiver' => 'rcv',
    'place'    => 'plc',
    'position' => 'pos',
    'company'  => 'cpy',
);

my $re = Regexp::Assemble->new->add(keys %subst);

my $str = "this is the receiver: [receiver] and this is the place: [place]";

$str =~ s/(?:\[($re)\])/$subst{$1}/g;
```

Comment: I'd use `map quotemeta, keys %subst`. `add` takes regex patterns, not text, but your method only works if the keys are text.

Comment: (Actually, I'd use Regexp::List instead of Regexp::Assemble when dealing with strings instead of patterns.)

Answer (score 0):

I get this with following:

```
/\[(receiver|place|position|company)\]/${"$+"}/ge;
```

$receiver $place $position $company should be global variable(our)